# lvalue required as increment operand (2)

Tags: c++

Its giving me this error for line `*(repetitions + x)++;` inside this for loop. Any clues  why?

```
for (int y = 0; y<hours; y++)
{
    if (*(array + x) == *(array + y))
    {
        *(repetitions + x)++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `*((repetitions + x)++)`.

Comment: I don't follow can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't increment the rvalue `repetitions + x`. This is the same error as writing:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
(a+b)++;     // ????
```

The `++` operator requires an lvalue, i.e. the designation of a variable. `a+b` is a temporary result and doesn't have a memory address, it can't be incremented.

It's possible that you meant to write `(*(repetitions + x))++;`, which could be more clearly expressed as `repetitions[x]++;`

Answer (score -1):

This parses as `*((repetitions + x)++)` -- that is, it tries to modify a constant address, then dereference it. Presumably you intended increment what the address pointed at instead.

You can do that a couple different ways. One would be to use parentheses. Another to use pre-increment:

```
++*(repetitions + x);
```

or:

```
(*(repetitions + x))++;
```

Comment: Or use brackets instead of `+` and `*`: `repetitions[x]++;`

Comment: (assuming `repetitions` is a pointer or other random access iterator)